# Как задать горячие клавиши в XFCE, чтобы они не пересекались?

Tags: linux, archlinux, hotkeys, xfce, xfce4

Дело в том, что я задал для Whisker (меню приложений) горячую клавишу на Win по старой привычке. Но помимо этого у меня есть ещё комбинация Win+Enter для быстрого запуска терминала. И каждый раз, когда я жму Win+Enter, прежде, чем откроется терминал, у меня открывается меню Whisker. Само собой это раздражает.

Есть ли какие-то идеи как это можно хитро исправить?

Дистрибутив: Arch Linux

DE: XFCE

Настройки горячих клавиш выглядят вот так:
[image: Скриншот настроек горячих клавиш]

Comment: В чем проблема поставить другой хоткей вместо win + enter? или уберите сам win (удалить  / заменить)

Comment: Клавиша Super - это [клавиша-модификатор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80). Аналогично Alt, Shift и Ctrl она не должна быть самостоятельным хоткеем. Поставьте Super+что-нибудь. У меня Whisker запускается на Super+Esc.